# calculated measure and filter by two different dimensions

Tags: filtering, mdx, dimension, measure

this works

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Pre] AS
SUM
(
-{
[Dim Event].[Ticket].&[Open]
},
(
[Measures].[Event Incidents Count]
)
)
Select  [Measures].[Pre] on 0
From Event
```

However, adding another dimension like this

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Pre] AS
SUM
(
-{
[Dim Event].[Ticket].&[Open]
,[Dim Category].[Status].&[OPEN]
},
(
[Measures].[Event Incidents Count]
)
)

Select  [Measures].[Pre] on 0
From Event
```

caused this error,

**Executing the query ...
Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function.
Execution complete**

how can I rewrite the second query to have two dimensions. 
BTW, it's for a cube Calculation,so I'm only going to use something like this

```
SUM
(
-{
[Dim Event].[Ticket].&[Open]
,[Dim Category].[Status].&[OPEN]
},
(
[Measures].[Event Incidents Count]
)
)
```

Update: Solution

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Pre] AS
SUM
(
CROSSJOIN(
- {
[Dim Event].[Ticket].&[Open] }
, - { [Dim Category].[Status].&[OPEN] }
)
,
[Measures].[Event Incidents Count]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might work..

```
SUM
(
-{
[Dim Event].[Ticket].&[Open]
},
{
[Dim Category].[Status].&[OPEN]
},
(
[Measures].[Event Incidents Count]
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Pre] AS
SUM
([Dim Event].[Ticket].&[Open] * [Dim Category].[Status].&[OPEN],
([Measures].[Event Incidents Count])
)

Select  [Measures].[Pre] on 0
From Event
```

Hop this help !